# css table td: box shadow cut on right side

Tags: css

ive got a css problem with td´s in a table row.
hovering on a td makes a box shadow visible but its always cut on the right side, except the last one. showing here: http://i39.tinypic.com/2ztdk6c.jpg

ive already tried to fix it by increasing z-index value up but it didnt fix it.

```
td:hover {-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px -1px #888;box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px -1px #888;z-index:100;}
```

how can i fix it so the box shadow shows on all 4 sides?
thanks

Comment: you need to set position `z-index` to take effect, unless you did in `td` styling

Comment: you are welcome :) I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set position for `z-index` to take effect, unless you already did in `td` style definition.